# Solr hierarchial facet performance improvement required

Tags: java, solr

Current facet implementation of hierarchial facet is based on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/HierarchicalFaceting with facet.prefix drilldown.

Due to data growth this approach has become slower and I'd like to imrpove it.

Current structure. (to describe a document cat be added to multiple categories, which makes pivot facet or nested json facetting not ideal)

```
Doc 1: 
  category: {l1}A1/
            {l1}A2/
            {l2}A1/B1/
            {l2}A2/B2/

Doc 2: 
  category: {l1}A1/
            {l1}A3/
            {l2}A1/B1
            {l2}A3/B3
            {l3}A1/B1/C1
            {l3}A3/B3/C3
```

Let's assume there are 7 levels deep and the UI has to show the first 4 levels deep.
The root nodes use to contain only 3 values so it was possible to create facets like, but this has now increased substantially:

```
facet.field={!key=l1_category facet.prefix="{l1}" v=category}
facet.field={!key=l2_category facet.prefix="{l2}" v=category}
facet.field={!key=l3_category facet.prefix="{l3}" v=category}
```

Then there was java logic that would process these facets and create the correct tree structure using recursive logic over each of the keys and by splitting the path's using 'contains'.

In the end it should look like (but with 4 levels, and the ability to filter down to 7)

```
 A1(2)
   B1(2)
     C1(1)
 A2(1)
   B2(1)
 A3(1)
   B3(1)
    C3(1)
```

I've already attempted to use nested json.facet's.
But I could not get the outer bucket value to prefix the inner one.

Ideally it would be an adjustment of the follow request, but I'm not sure if such an improvement is possible:

```
json.facet =  {
    "categories_lvl1": {
      "type": "terms",
      "field": "categories",
      "limit": 50,
      "prefix":"{l1}",
      "facet": {
        "categories_lvl2": {
          "type": "terms",
          "field": "categories",
           "prefix":"{l2}", <-- instead of this it should be a reference to the parent bucket term with a regex applied, because now it will  give invalid combinations
          "limit": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Would there be a better data structure and/or better search request option to build the tree? (current Solr version 8.11.1)**

I know a create all combinations as 'nested' documents solution(and then use those to facet), but this would be a heavy operation and for searching it's currently not necesssary + could make counts more difficult.